# auftauchen in übertragenem Sinne

Tags: sentence-structure

Sometimes i want to express that: Problems surface , Questions surface, People show up/pop up

Are the following sentences correct? Klingen die schief?

> Neue Leute tauchen auf --> Neu people show up

> .... tja und du machst das bis neue Probleme auftauchen ... yeah and you do that until new problems arise
>
> ... und auf der Suche nach neuen Medikamenten tauchen neue Fragen auf ... and on the search for new medicines new questions arise

Klingen die Sätze schief? Sind die vielleicht falsch?

Comment: As a side note: If something sounds schief in German, it means it's off-key (sharp or flat) and related to music. If you want to say wonky, go with _komisch_ or _eigenartig_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auftauchen has the implication that it's somewhat unexpected ([See Duden 2a) and 2b)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auftauchen))

> Neue Leute tauchen auf --> Neu people show up

This works as in

> Bei dem Konzert waren anfangs nur 20 Leute, aber für den Headliner sind nochmal 40 mehr aufgetaucht.

> tja und du machst das bis neue Probleme auftauchen

Depending on how likely you think problems will arise (and it seems there have been problems in the past) you might want to go with *auftreten*  instead of *auftauchen* ([Duden 4a) and 4b)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auftreten))

> ... und auf der Suche nach neuen Medikamenten tauchen neue Fragen auf ... and on the search for new medicines new questions arise

This works as well.